# Text positionning in a TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want to have some text near a special point of a picture, without overlapping any line, but always sticking to the same start point from the left (or end point from the right), whatever the text's length may be (always quite short, though, but I'd liked to be able to change this text without having to re-calculate its position each time I do).

In the example below, I have written "1 cm" in black at right of the vertical dashed line, and, as another example on this very same picture, I have added "1.75 mm" in red. Both start at the same distance from the dashed line (the red 1 exactly overwriting the black 1), that's what I want.

[image: parallelogram with its height as vertical dashed line and red text "1.75 mm" overwriting black "1 cm" at right of the dashed height line]

But the quite satisfying solution I have found, so far, looks a bit over complicated to me. I haven't found a better way using other things like using `right`, `auto` or `midway` keywords, anchors etc. (many other ways tend to put the text farther from the dashed line).

There are many similar questions, but I haven't found the one solving this case yet.

Is there any way to have the same result with a shorter or better written code?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary {positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]

\draw[semithick,black] (2, 0) -- (8, 0) -- (6, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
\draw[semithick,black!80,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1pt] (2, 0) -- (2, 3);
\begin{scope}[node distance=0]
    \node (m) at (1,1.5) {};
    \node [font=\tiny,right=of m] {$1$ cm};
    \node [font=\tiny,red,right=of m] {$1.75$ mm};        
\end{scope}
\draw[semithick,black!80] (2, 0.5) -- (2.5, 0.5) -- (2.5, 0);
\draw node[font=\tiny] at (4.75, -0.45) {$3$ cm};
\draw node[font=\tiny,rotate=-55] at (7.5, 1.75) {$2$ cm};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

NB the solution above is only "quite" satisfying because when changing the scale, the texts are not positioned correctly any more; but anyway I have tried to use `scalebox` too and I think I'll have to modify several things when changing the scale anyway, including a more reasonable font size, so there may not be any solution including a satisfying scaling-ability too, so that's not required in my question. I'll write two versions of this picture (tiny and large sized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, 
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25, %transform shape,
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=2pt, font=\tiny, text=black}
                        ]  
\draw[semithick]    (2,0) coordinate (a) 
                            to["\qty{3}{cm}"]
                    (8,0) coordinate (b) 
                            to["\qty{3}{cm}" ',sloped] 
                    (6, 3) --  (0, 3) -- (2,0);
\draw[gray,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1pt] 
                    (2, 0) to["\qty{1.75}{cm}"] (2, 3) coordinate (c);
\pic[draw, angle radius=2mm,
    ]               {right angle = b--a--c};                  % <------
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks good, and replacing `1.75 mm` by `1 cm` still puts the text at the same start point from the left. Is the `inner sep` parameter the one meant to control how far the text should be from the matching line?

Comment: Moreover it looks like I can resize it quite well in a scalebox! That's great! Many thanks!!